# ejb bean instance pool jboss EAP 6.1

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

In our project we are migrating from JBoss5 to Jboss EAP 6.1.
When I was going through the configuration to be used in Jboss EAP 6.1, I stumbled upon below:

```
<pools>
<bean-instance-pools>
<strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="1" instance-acquisitiontimeout-unit="MILLISECONDS"/>
<strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="1" instance-acquisitiontimeout-unit="MILLISECONDS"/>
</bean-instance-pools>
</pools>
```

I am not clear about the max-pool-size argument.Is this limit 20 instances per Stateless EJB bean deployed on JBoss or pool will go only up to 20 instances irrespective of the no of stateless EJB beans.

Comment: Historically I think there were 20 pooled instances per bean. I agree its very vague, the naming would suggest there are max 20 pooled beans in total, but that can't be right since that would cause issues as soon as you have more than 20 EJBs. Its also very helpful that this part is not documented :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html-single/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/index.html#sect-Configuring_Bean_Pools) says

> the maximum size of the bean pool.

Also, if you go to admin panel of EAP and go to Profile -> Container -> EJB3 -> Bean Pools -> "Need Help?" it says

> Max Pool Size:    The maximum number of bean instances that the pool can
>   hold at a given point in time

I would interpret that to mean that pool will go only up to 20 instances.

---

Edit: in retrospect, [answer by Sergey Kosarev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548493/365237) saying it is per instance seems convincing enough that you should probably believe that instead.

Comment: how it decides which beans should be instantiated ?

Comment: @Rips that depends on the configuration, either beans are instantiated on application startup or on first use. As to if more beans are needed than allowed in the pool, I don't know which beans would be preferred.

Comment: This interpreation is wrong, Sergeys answer is correct. If you change the "org.jboss.as.ejb3" Loglevel to DEBUG and start JBoss, you will see a list of statements like 

    "Using pool config StrictMaxPoolConfig{name=slsb-strict-max-pool, maxPoolSize=20, timeoutUnit=MINUTES, timeout=5} to create pool for Stateless EJB xxx"
    
which means that JBoss is creating a new pool for each SLSB type.

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with eis.
Here is code of Wildfly 8.2.1
StatelessSessionComponent.java

```
public StatelessSessionComponent(final StatelessSessionComponentCreateService slsbComponentCreateService) {
    super(slsbComponentCreateService);

    StatelessObjectFactory<StatelessSessionComponentInstance> factory = new StatelessObjectFactory<StatelessSessionComponentInstance>() {
        @Override
        public StatelessSessionComponentInstance create() {
            return (StatelessSessionComponentInstance) createInstance();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy(StatelessSessionComponentInstance obj) {
            obj.destroy();
        }
    };
    final PoolConfig poolConfig = slsbComponentCreateService.getPoolConfig();
    if (poolConfig == null) {
        ROOT_LOGGER.debug("Pooling is disabled for Stateless EJB " + slsbComponentCreateService.getComponentName());
        this.pool = null;
        this.poolName = null;
    } else {
        ROOT_LOGGER.debug("Using pool config " + poolConfig + " to create pool for Stateless EJB " + slsbComponentCreateService.getComponentName());
        this.pool = poolConfig.createPool(factory);
        this.poolName = poolConfig.getPoolName();
    }

    this.timeoutMethod = slsbComponentCreateService.getTimeoutMethod();
    this.weakAffinity = slsbComponentCreateService.getWeakAffinity();
}
```

As I see pool is non-static field and is created for every type of Component(ejb class).